# Fastest way to compare 100 length numeric strings in java

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I am building an efficient system.I have to compare strings which are numeric and can be of length 0 to 128 and may have zeros at the start.

I looked in google and found few posts but no one considers string length as long as 100.

I have created a comparator that checks null, starting 0, length and character by character comparison.

I have another option of using BigInteger. But undecided which is safe and fast.

and if BigInteger is fast I dont have any idea what makes its implementation fast.

Would like to know what is best, safe, and robust practice for comparing numeric strings of length  at least 100.

Why Second one with big integer is running fast?

////

public static boolean isGreaterSequence1(final String newSequence, final String oldSequence) {

```
    if (newSequence == null || oldSequence == null || newSequence.isEmpty() || oldSequence.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    final String oldSequenceModified = getWithoutStartZero(oldSequence);

    final String newSequenceModified = getWithoutStartZero(newSequence);
    if (oldSequenceModified.compareTo(newSequenceModified) > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

   public static String getWithoutStartZero(final String input) {
    final int length = input.length();
    int end = 0;
    while (end < length) {
        if (input.charAt(end) != '0') {
            break;
        }
        end++;
    }

    return input.substring(end, length);
}

public static boolean tempCompare(final String newSequence, final String oldSequence) {
    final BigInteger ns = new BigInteger(newSequence);
    final BigInteger os = new BigInteger(oldSequence);
    final int res = ns.compareTo(os);
    if (res > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

//

Comment: Please clarify if leading zeros should be ignored. i.e. is "00096" > "096" > "96"?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking for...

Comment: Positive and Zeros must be ignored

Comment: Gut feeling: avoid any conversion. Comparing sequences of characters should always be faster than converting huge number string to BigInteger. But of course, this depends on the further usage. If there is actually a need for a later step to convert the strings to numbers; you might as well do it upfront.

Comment: Only Usecase is to compare strings and return boolean

Answer (score 1):

Get length. Then, start iterating both strings skipping leading zeros, count them. Compare `length - zeroes`. If not equal return the bigger as the bigger one.

Otherwise, continue iterating comparing character for character. If not equal, one is greater than the other.

The trick is to manually skip zeros and continuing character-by-character comparison from there. This way, you won't read any character twice. Normally I would advise against getting length, but in java it's given anyways, and there is no way avoid it.

Converting to bigint won't be faster, because it needs to read the string anyways. Well read and parse, here you only read it.

Anyways, it looks like micro-optimization to be honest. It would matter only for comparing strings of greatly differing length.

Comment: well I thought the same and did exactly whatever you mentioned and then ran a test case with 100000 strings to see if big integer takes more time or this implementation. and found big integer is taking half the time. No idea why its taking less time.

Comment: You would need to post concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can left padding with 0 the shortest string and than compare them as normal strings.

So if the strings are

```
public static final String ZEROS = "0000000000000000000000000000000"; // As long as you need
public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length > str2.length) {
        str2 = ZEROS.substr(0, str1.length - str2.length) + str2;
    } else {
        str1 = ZEROS.substr(0, str2.length - str1.length) + str1;
    }
    return str1.compareTo(str2);
}
```

If your string can't start with zeros you can do a better implementation as follow:

```
public int compareIfNotStartingWith0(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length != str2.length) {
        return str1.length - str2.length;
    }
    return str1.compareTo(str2);
}
```

Comment: is this faster than which other ways?

Answer (score 0):

First code snippet for comparing strings was suppose to be the winner but some how I was getting less time for executing big integer code snippet. This happened because I had a apache logger in my string compare code that was taking all extra time and it was not present in big integer code. So big integer slow because it does extra work of converting string to big integer.